# Django - One URL links to two views?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-authentication

For my home page, I want to be able to have the generic login form, so I linked the homepage URL to the generic login view, like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', login),
```

Now, I also want to have the registration form and view in the homepage as well. This view is called the main_page view. What is the best way for me to be able to use both those views (and the variables which the two views render) in my homepage URL?

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own view to do this. You can't use the default login view but you can use other pieces Django provides:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in
This is how you login a user.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.forms
This is a login form if you don't wanna write your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you link 2 url's to single view then Django will only load the view which it encountered first. So no point linking 2 url's to single view.

Few advice's for you:

1. On login page why not give a link to registration page, if user is not registered then he/she can register.
2. Or Differentiate your URL with a query string parameter. In case of registration page pass a query string param. Then in the login view check for the query string param, if exists redirect it to registration view else show login page. your homepage url with query string will look like

   http://www.example.com?page=r #you can choose any key value pair for query string